# Login as ec2-user won't go away

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 instance based off of a RHEL 6.4 64bit AMI.  After setting up this server with programs, etc; I created my own AMI Image off of it.  All good, until I tried creating a new instance off of my AMI.  When I try to login as root, it asks me to login in as ec2-user.  My modified instance from which the AMI was built was already corrected for this and so I don't see how it can come back.

Your help, as always is appreciated!

--Roger

Comment: I hate answering my own question, but I found the answer in this excellent post: http://gurjeet-tech.blogspot.com/2012/02/allowing-root-access-in-amis.html

Comment: Want me to answer for you? :)